# Powermockito throws an OutOfMemory exception when stubbing FileOutputStream

Tags: java, powermock

I am not sure why this happens, but when I run the test code I get an OutOfMemoryException.

Test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(UploadBulkRefundAction.class)
public class UploadBulkRefundActionTest {

    @Mock
    private File file;
    @Mock
    private BulkRefundsForm bulkRefundsForm;
    @Mock
    private FormFile spreadsheetFile;
    @Mock
    private InputStream is;
    @Mock
    private FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(File.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(FileOutputStream.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(IOUtils.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(FileOutputStream.class).withArguments(file).thenReturn(fileOutputStream);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldStoreFileIntoTempFile() throws Exception {
        when(File.createTempFile("tomcat-","bulkrefunds.xlsx")).thenReturn(file);
        when(bulkRefundsForm.getSpreadsheetFile()).thenReturn(spreadsheetFile);
        when(spreadsheetFile.getInputStream()).thenReturn(is);
        UploadBulkRefundAction action=new UploadBulkRefundAction();

        action.execute(null, bulkRefundsForm, null, null);

        verify(spreadsheetFile).getInputStream();
        verifyNew(FileOutputStream.class).withArguments(file);

        verifyStatic();
        File.createTempFile("tomcat-", "bulkrefunds.xlsx");

        verifyStatic();
        IOUtils.copy(is, fileOutputStream);
    }

}
```

Class Under Test:

```
public class UploadBulkRefundAction extends MossoAction {
    @Override
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm f, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     Exception {
        BulkRefundsForm bulkRefundsForm=(BulkRefundsForm)f;
        File tempFile = storeExcelSheetInATempFile(bulkRefundsForm);
        return null;
    }

    private File storeExcelSheetInATempFile(BulkRefundsForm bulkRefundsForm) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream=null;
        FileOutputStream outputStream=null;
        try{
            File tempFile = File.createTempFile("tomcat-", "bulkrefunds.xlsx");
            inputStream = bulkRefundsForm.getSpreadsheetFile().getInputStream();
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
            return tempFile;
        }finally{
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [source code for IOUtils.copy](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.java#IOUtils.copy%28java.io.InputStream,java.io.OutputStream%29) includes a loop which will never terminate if your `InputStream` fails to return the value '-1' from its `read()` method.

I would guess that your mock will return '0' by default from methods with an `int` return type, so your test code enters an infinite loop which endlessly writes 4k sized byte arrays to the `OutputStream`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I fixed it with the following additional line:  PowerMockito.when(is.read(any(byte[].class))).thenReturn(1,-1); Not sure how I missed it..